# MySQL select multiple rows with AND condition

Tags: mysql

I'm sure there's a simple query for this, I just can't think of it.

I have a table like so:

[image]

I'd like to select the jobno when conditions from multiple rows are true.
For example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT jobno FROM jobProps WHERE ((class = 1 AND type = 3) OR (class = 2 AND type = 3))
```

Will return 2020001.00 if either condition is true, but I'm try to do something like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT jobno FROM jobProps WHERE ((class = 1 AND type = 3) AND (class = 2 AND type = 3))
```

But it doesn't return anything. How can I get my AND condition to work correctly?

EDIT:
I think this is working now:

```
select x.jobno
from ( SELECT jobno FROM jobProps WHERE class=1 AND type=3) as x
inner join ( SELECT jobno FROM jobProps WHERE class=2 AND type=3) 
as y
on x.jobno = y.jobno
ORDER BY x.jobno
```

Let me know if there's a better way...

Comment: Use a subquery for each condition, and join them to find all rows that meet all conditions.

Comment: combining conditions with `AND` tries to match all the conditions on the same row. A single row can't have both `class = 1` and `class = 2`.

Answer (score 1):

you can run subqueries for that

```
SELECT DISTINCT jobno 
FROM jobProps 
WHERE  (class = 1 AND type = 3)
 AND EXIStS( SELECT 1 FROM jobProps WHERE class = 2 AND type = 3)
```

Comment: Sorry @nbk, I thought it was working, but it just returns the full table.

Comment: i corrected the answer see if that is a s fast as your solution